# Calling a event method on UI

Tags: ios, ios7, uibutton, uitextfield

I have a textfield like so:

```
_txtfield1.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

How do I make this call my submit button pressed method?

```
- (void) submitButtonPressed
{
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your class conforms to UITextFieldDelegate in your header file, then implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == _txtfield1)
    {
        [self submitButtonPressed];
    }
}
```